# 'gcc' not recognized though C:\MinGW\bin added to path

Tags: compile, gcc, mingw

I installed mingw from the mingw installer and installed all the basic packages needed.
I can run gcc if I give the address of the folder to cmd but not without it.
I will attach all the images. The OS is windows 11

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you restart Command Prompt after modifying the environment variables? Did you save the changes to the environment variables?

Comment: yes, I did both of the said things

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: it is windows 11

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu Linux:

```
$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

... tells that the gcc executable is NOT in `$HOME/bin` nor in `/bin` - depending on the actual MinGW setup that might differ though.

Check `which gcc` and see...

*Note: Sometimes there is trickery involved; `type -a gcc` may help then.*

Also: `cygpath -w $(which gcc)` might tell what to put in Windows-based configs (e.g. %PATH%).

---

**More 'Linux' stuff...**

If you have e.g. `mlocate` installed.

```
$ locate -i "*gcc"  
/diff/usr/lib/gcc
...
/usr/bin/c89-gcc
/usr/bin/c99-gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc
/usr/lib/gcc
/usr/share/gcc
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/gcc
/usr/share/doc/gcc
/usr/share/doc/gcc-8-base/gcc
/usr/share/doc/gcc-9-base/gcc
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.13.0-52-generic/include/config/CC_IS_GCC
/usr/src/linux-hwe-5.13-headers-5.13.0-52/scripts/dummy-tools/gcc
```

If no `mlocate`, then maybe use the slower:

```
$ cd / && find 2>/dev/null -iname "*gcc" -type f
./usr/bin/c99-gcc
./usr/bin/c89-gcc
./usr/share/bash-completion/completions/gcc
./usr/src/linux-hwe-5.13-headers-5.13.0-52/scripts/dummy-tools/gcc
./usr/src/linux-headers-5.13.0-52-generic/include/config/CC_IS_GCC
```

---

A proper setup of MinGW or other Cygwin (-based) stuff should have installation, instructions and/or startup -scripting that provides this though.

If it doesn't, then that is a 'bug' in my opinion,
i.e. *remove the guesswork and required prior knowledge; it stops new users from getting things to work.*

Often, all it takes is a single short sentence. Especially if ýou can point it out, as provided by someone else.

Comment: Thanks for the response! sorry for not stating my os in the question, I will edit it. Also I was able to get gcc to work finally https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73932517/mingw-directory-added-to-path-but-not-showing-as-an-active-path-variable